# Extracting html tags based on attribute

Tags: java, html

I have a crawled page and I have retrieved html of the page into `String` object.

Now i want to parse this string and to extract all tags that have `itemprop` defined into an array that would be associative for example

```
String[] itemprops;
itemprops['title'] = "Some title";
itemprops['description'] = "Some description";
```

Can I do this with regex somehow or is there some library that can do this.

Comment: The code you posted is neither Java, neither JavaScript... ? And DO NOT parse xml/html with regexes!

Comment: [When you parse HTML with regex, a kitten dies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not). Use a DOM library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). It's an HTML scraping and parsing library that's exactly what you want.

In your case, you can do something like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTMLString);
String title = doc.select("title").text();
String description = doc.select("meta[name=description]").attr("content");
```

The select() function uses [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to get elements.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that the html which you use follows strict syntax. Because broken syntax may cause parsing exception or loss data.

Comment: It's from rotten tomatoes website, so I guess it's fine